# Summarise multi-dimensional array by month

Tags: r

I have a multi-dimensional array where the 3rd dimension represents time. For purposes of this question, let's use the `ozone` dataset from the `plyr` package:

```
> str(ozone)
 num [1:24, 1:24, 1:72] 260 258 258 254 252 252 250 248 248 248 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ lat : chr [1:24] "-21.2" "-18.7" "-16.2" "-13.7" ...
  ..$ long: chr [1:24] "-113.8" "-111.3" "-108.8" "-106.3" ...
  ..$ time: chr [1:72] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

From the documentation:

> The data are monthly ozone averages on a very coarse 24 by 24 grid covering Central America, from Jan 1995 to Dec 2000. The data is stored in a 3d area with the first two dimensions representing latitude and longitude, and the third representing time.

What I would like to do is to create the monthly average for each of the lat/long cells. I can do this for a single lat/long combination with `tapply` like so:

```
> tapply(ozone[1,1,], rep(1:12, 6), mean)
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       11       12 
264.6667 257.6667 255.0000 251.3333 257.6667 265.0000 274.0000 275.3333 277.0000 285.0000 283.0000 273.3333
```

but I am stumped on doing this over the entire array at once. `apply` will let me select the dimensions to operate over (`MARGIN`), `tapply` will let me use a factor to select slices (`INDEX`), but I need both.

I am open to suggestions but prefer to work with arrays rather than data frames due to the size and complexity of the data.

---

Two excellent answers below from **GKi** and **G. Grothendieck**, many thanks to both. I have put them through `microbenchmark` and these are the results:

```
> microbenchmark(
    GKi1 = apply(array(ozone, c(dim(ozone)[1:2], 12, dim(ozone)[3]/12), c(dimnames(ozone)[1:2], list(month=1:12, year=1995:2000))), 1:3, mean),
    GKi2 = simplify2array(lapply(split(dimnames(plyr::ozone)[[3]], 1:12), \(x) apply(plyr::ozone[,,x], 1:2, mean))),
    Grothendieck = apply(ozone, 1:2, month_mean),
  times=100)

Unit: milliseconds
         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
         GKi1 21.67954 22.99889 25.73446 23.89190 27.26137  46.26843   100
         GKi2 20.90931 22.90361 26.64572 23.88572 30.76128  45.16404   100
 Grothendieck 40.98800 43.26854 49.51313 44.73214 52.28114 266.12759   100
```

Comment: See also [Aggregate an array based on the dimension names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36978155/10488504) and [Applying a function to a multidimensional array with grouping variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16135877/10488504).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can divide the time dimension in month and year and use then `apply`.

```
x <- plyr::ozone
x <- array(x, c(dim(x)[1:2], 12, dim(x)[3]/12),
           c(dimnames(x)[1:2], list(month=1:12, year=1995:2000)))
#dim(x) <- c(dim(x)[1:2], 12, dim(x)[3]/12) #Alternative without names
. <- apply(x, 1:3, mean)
.[1,1,]
#       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
#264.6667 257.6667 255.0000 251.3333 257.6667 265.0000 274.0000 275.3333 
#       9       10       11       12 
#277.0000 285.0000 283.0000 273.3333
```

Another option can be.

```
. <- simplify2array(lapply(split(dimnames(plyr::ozone)[[3]], 1:12), \(x)
                    apply(plyr::ozone[,,x], 1:2, mean)))
.[1,1,]
#       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
#264.6667 257.6667 255.0000 251.3333 257.6667 265.0000 274.0000 275.3333 
#       9       10       11       12 
#277.0000 285.0000 283.0000 273.3333
```

Or using `tapply` inside `apply` (based on the grat answer of @g-grothendieck)

```
. <- apply(plyr::ozone, 1:2, tapply, rep(1:12, 6), mean)
.[,1,1]
#aperm(., c(2,3,1))[1,1,] #Alternative
#       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
#264.6667 257.6667 255.0000 251.3333 257.6667 265.0000 274.0000 275.3333 
#       9       10       11       12 
#277.0000 285.0000 283.0000 273.3333
```

Using `by` in `apply`.

```
. <- apply(plyr::ozone, 1:2, by, rep(1:12, 6), mean)
.[,1,1]
#       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
#264.6667 257.6667 255.0000 251.3333 257.6667 265.0000 274.0000 275.3333 
#       9       10       11       12 
#277.0000 285.0000 283.0000 273.3333
```

If speed matters `rowMeans` could be used.

```
. <- rowMeans(`dim<-`(plyr::ozone, c(dim(plyr::ozone)[1:2], 12,
  dim(plyr::ozone)[3]/12)), dims=3)
.[1,1,]
# [1] 264.6667 257.6667 255.0000 251.3333 257.6667 265.0000 274.0000 275.3333
# [9] 277.0000 285.0000 283.0000 273.3333
```

Benchmark:

```
set.seed(42)
a <- array(runif(24 * 24 * 72), c(24, 24, 72))

bench::mark(check = FALSE, #Some have attr and have not the same order
  applyDim = apply(`dim<-`(a, c(dim(a)[1:2], 12, dim(a)[3]/12)), 1:3, mean),
  split = simplify2array(lapply(split(seq_len(dim(a)[3]), 1:12), \(x)
                    apply(a[,,x], 1:2, mean))),
  applyTapply = apply(a, 1:2, tapply, rep_len(1:12, dim(a)[3]), mean),
  applyBy = apply(a, 1:2, by, rep_len(1:12, dim(a)[3]), mean),
  rowMeans = rowMeans(`dim<-`(a, c(dim(a)[1:2], 12, dim(a)[3]/12)), dims=3)
)
#  expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 applyDim      25.5ms   29.2ms     33.4   864.33KB     41.2    17    21
#2 split         30.6ms   33.6ms     30.1   984.13KB     35.7    16    19
#3 applyTapply   36.2ms   38.8ms     22.6     2.52MB     35.9    12    19
#4 applyBy      177.1ms  179.1ms      5.56    2.71MB     35.2     3    19
#5 rowMeans     130.9µs  155.1µs   5149.    378.09KB     38.0  2575    19
```

Comment: Aaaaaaah, that's a nifty trick indeed (so answer accepted), but still a trick. Is there no declarative solution, much like `tapply`s ability to slice using a criterion in a (set of) factor(s)?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Please see my updated question with microbenchmark comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark comparison! Even if the first two ways are faster, I personally would prefer using something like `apply(ozone, 1:2, tapply, rep(1:12, 6), mean)` as it is clearer what is done. Maybe also exchanging the part `rep(1:12, 6),` with something like `rep_len(1:12, dim(ozone)[3])`.

Comment: I agree totally with you on the readability issue! Too bad there isn't a clean out-of-the-box solution, i.e. `tapply` on higher dimensionality arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Using the array defined reproducibly in the Note at the end we have the following using `apply`.  The precise output was not defined but if you wanted a different order of dimensions then use `aperm`.

```
month_mean <- function(x) c(tapply(x, rep(1:12, each = 6), mean))
aa <- apply(a, 1:2, month_mean)
```

Now check the result

```
# check
all.equal(aa[, 4, 9], month_mean(a[4, 9, ]))
## [1] TRUE

# another check
for(i in 1:24) for(j in 1:24) {
  check <- all.equal(aa[, i, j], month_mean(a[i, j, ]))
  if (!check) stop("not equal")
}
```

### Note

```
set.seed(123)
a <- array(runif(24 * 24 * 72), c(24, 24, 72))
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Please see my updated question with microbenchmark comparison.